# Possible php caching on Netsons

Tags: php, caching

I have a php website hosted by Netsons.

**What happens:**

I write my index.php, then I watch it on my browser (loading it for the first time) and I see the page that I made, for example a text saying `Hello 1`.
At some point I make a change on the index.php. For example, I change the text to `Hello 2`.

I refresh the browser window, but it is still showing `Hello 1`.
I try to add a fake GET variable at the end of the path: For example `http://my.website.address/**?a=1**`. Then it works! I see `Hello 2` and every time make a change on index.php.

E.g. changing the text to `Hello 3`. I can load `http://my.website.address/**?a=1**` and I see my changes. But now if I load the page without the variable I see `Hello 1` again.

**First theory: It's my browser cache**

I clean the cache and reload the page... but I still see `Hello 1`. I try opening the page with another browser on the same PC (and this is the fist time that I use that browser... there is no cache) but I still see `Hello 1`.

Even if I open the website on another PC that has never visited that page, It continue to be `Hello 1`. I try the "fake variable" loophole it works!

So I guess it is not the browser cache.

**Second theory: My Internet Provider has a proxy server that caches the pages**

So I call a friend that lives far away from me and has a different Internet Provider and I ask him to open the website, but he reads `Hello 1`. The "fake variable" loophole works even here!

**Third theory: There is a kind of caching system on Netsons**

Someone knows where the problem could be and how can I fix it (without using fake variables)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's a long shot but it might be a faulty rewriterule in a .htaccess

Comment: Did you ask Netsons? They would know the answer... If you have shell access, you can try to `touch index.php` to update its timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-cache]
```

in the file .htaccess in your public_html folder.